# Azure Container Registry image pulls are very slow with image size ~150 MBs

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

When deploying an image to an AKS instance, the image pull from the ACR (Premium SKU) is very slow, even for "small" images around ~150 MBs in size.

Both the AKS resource and the ACR resource are in the Canada East region.

Here is an example:

```
root@076fff2831b2:/tmp# kubectl describe pod application-service-59bcf96874-pvrmb
Name:           application-service-59bcf96874-pvrmb
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           aks-41067869-1/10.255.13.163
Start Time:     Tue, 11 Feb 2020 18:15:53 -0500
Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/instance=application-service
                app.kubernetes.io/name=application-service
                pod-template-hash=59bcf96874
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.255.13.175
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/application-service-59bcf96874
Containers:
  application-service:
    Container ID:   docker://0e86526a293d9055d482a09f043f0be68c594244fe4216f8fb190bc2caf6b65b
    Image:          myacr01.azurecr.io/microservices/application-service:0.0.6
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://myacr01.azurecr.io/microservices/application-service@sha256:cfbb3ffa7adc52da9cc0b8d7f78376076ea712025b59df8e406c559d369f4085
    Port:           3000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Tue, 11 Feb 2020 18:35:00 -0500
      Finished:     Tue, 11 Feb 2020 18:35:00 -0500
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  5
    Liveness:       http-get https://:http/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get https://:http/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      PORT:                        3000
      undefined:                   undefined
    Mounts:
      /kvmnt from application-service-kv-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from application-service-token-9jk8j (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  application-service-kv-volume:
    Type:       FlexVolume (a generic volume resource that is provisioned/attached using an exec based plugin)
    Driver:     azure/kv
    FSType:
    SecretRef:  &LocalObjectReference{Name:kvcreds,}
    ReadOnly:   false
    Options:    map[keyvaultname:testIt2 keyvaultobjectnames:APPLICATION-SVC-SQLDB-CS;INGESTION-CONSUMER-EHB-CS;INGESTION-PRODUCER-EHB-CS keyvaultobjecttypes:secret;secret;secret tenantid:REMOVED usepodidentity:false usevmmanagedidentity:false]
  application-service-token-9jk8j:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  application-service-token-9jk8j
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From                     Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled  20m                    default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/application-service-59bcf96874-pvrmb to aks-41067869-1
  Normal   Pulling    20m                    kubelet, aks-41067869-1  Pulling image "myacr01.azurecr.io/microservices/application-service:0.0.6"
  Normal   Pulled     4m39s                  kubelet, aks-41067869-1  Successfully pulled image "myacr01.azurecr.io/microservices/application-service:0.0.6"
  Normal   Started    3m36s (x4 over 4m33s)  kubelet, aks-41067869-1  Started container application-service
  Warning  BackOff    3m4s (x11 over 4m30s)  kubelet, aks-41067869-1  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulled     2m52s (x4 over 4m32s)  kubelet, aks-41067869-1  Container image "myacr01.azurecr.io/microservices/application-service:0.0.6" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    2m51s (x5 over 4m33s)  kubelet, aks-41067869-1  Created container application-service
```

Some details were modified/removed for privacy reasons.

However, the thing to note is the ~15m needed to go from a state of "Pulling" to "Pulled" for an image from an ACR.

This issue is occurring daily. The Azure Insights blade of the AKS instance shows a maximum of 26% node CPU and 14.32% node memory utilization over the last 7 days.

How we can go about troubleshooting this further to determine the possible causes of delays?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Heard many people complain that Canada East is at capacity.  It may or not be related to your specific case.

Comment: i'm afraid that contacting azure support is your only option: it doesn't seem like the problem is on your side...

Comment: Thanks **CSharpRocks** and **morgwai**.  I'll try Azure Support.

Comment: Did you ever hear anything about this? 9 months later and I'm seeing it take more than 15 minutes to pull an image based on mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework. This makes cluster scaling very slow to respond to node depletion as it seems that nodes don't share the container cache, so they each have to pull the image before they can start up.